# TypeError: Cannot read property 'localtime' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't seem to find where I've gone wrong. I've checked the how the response from the API is structured and comparing it with my code to see if I messed up with that, but that doesn't seem to be the case. The problem could be the way that I'm trying to read data from the object but I've searched and I could not find anything showing that the way I was doing it was wrong.

My code:

```
import React from 'react'
import './Weather.css'
import axios from 'axios'

// Connects to weather API to get current weather data
class Weather extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            data: {},
            city: 'Gaborone'
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.apiCall(this.state.city)
    }

    apiCall(newCity){
        //Method is called when a new city is chosen
        axios.get(`http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=18dc0623507d4466ae7100225202308&q=${newCity}`).then(res =>{
            this.setState({data: res.data})
        })

    }

    update(){
        setInterval(this.apiCall(this.state.city), 1000)
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {JSON.stringify(this.state.data.location.localtime)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Weather
```

Response from the API:

```
{
    "location": {
        "name": "Gaborone",
        "region": "South-East",
        "country": "Botswana",
        "lat": -24.65,
        "lon": 25.91,
        "tz_id": "Africa/Gaborone",
        "localtime_epoch": 1598190355,
        "localtime": "2020-08-23 15:45"
    },
    "current": {
        "last_updated_epoch": 1598189409,
        "last_updated": "2020-08-23 15:30",
        "temp_c": 24.0,
        "temp_f": 75.2,
        "is_day": 1,
        "condition": {
            "text": "Sunny",
            "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/113.png",
            "code": 1000
        },
        "wind_mph": 6.9,
        "wind_kph": 11.2,
        "wind_degree": 60,
        "wind_dir": "ENE",
        "pressure_mb": 1021.0,
        "pressure_in": 30.6,
        "precip_mm": 0.0,
        "precip_in": 0.0,
        "humidity": 22,
        "cloud": 0,
        "feelslike_c": 23.2,
        "feelslike_f": 73.7,
        "vis_km": 10.0,
        "vis_miles": 6.0,
        "uv": 6.0,
        "gust_mph": 8.3,
        "gust_kph": 13.3
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial state does not have a `location` property:

```
this.state = {
    data: {},
    city: 'Gaborone'
}
```

You could give it a `location` property object with an empty `localtime` property initially:

```
this.state = {
    data: {
      location: {
        localtime: ''
      }
    },
    city: 'Gaborone'
}
```

Or, with optional chaining in the `render` method instead:

```
<div>
    {this.state.data.location?.localtime)
</div>
```

Note that `JSON.stringify` isn't needed - the `localtime` property will already be a plain normal string, which is fine to render.